# grab first name from field containing first/last name and extra information

Tags: mysql, string, suffix

I have a field (Called OWNER) that contains the following:

LastName  FirstName  MiddleInitial  Status

everything is separated by spaces and there are no commas after the LastName. I want just the FirstName and MiddleIntial, the status always starts with HRS and may or may not have additional characters. Right now I have:

Right(Trim([tblOutput.OWNER]),Len(Trim([tblOutput.OWNER]))-InStr(1,[tblOutput.OWNER]," "))

But I can't seem to get rid of the additional text containing the 'HRS'. I am sure it is something I am doing wrong when I try to strip the HRS off the above result.

Comment: show examples input/output/desired output

Comment: **Input: HALE VIRGINIA S HRS
LICARI JOHN M HRS ETAL
PARLIER DONNA HRS
HOGGARD NANCY CANFIELD HRS **Present Output: VIRGINIA S HRS
JOHN M HRS ETAL
DONNA HRS
NANCY CANFIELD HRS ***Desired: VIRGINIA S 
JOHN M 
DONNA 
NANCY CANFIELD

Answer (score 0):

Finally had some time to get back to this. Here is what I have so far, but now the problem is with the Suffix.

Here is the Query:

SELECT tblOutput.PID, Trim(Left([tblOutput.OWNER],InStr(1,[tblOutput.OWNER],"HRS")-1)) AS HRSLoc, Right(Trim([HRSLoc]),Len(Trim([HRSLoc]))-InStr(1,[HRSLoc]," ")) AS FName, Left([HRSLoc],InStr(1,[HRSLoc]," ")-1) AS LName, Right([FName],InStr(StrReverse([FName])," ")) AS Suffix
FROM tblOutput INNER JOIN green ON tblOutput.PID = green.PID
ORDER BY tblOutput.PID;

Here is a screen shot of the output:

[image: Acess query output]

I am unable to make the query grab matching items from a list for the Suffix such as "JR", "SR", "MD", Etc. So right now I have the last name correct but the First Name also contains the Suffix, which I need to remove so I can rearrange the name in output as FirstName + MiddleInitial (if there is one) + LastName + Suffix.